# How do I return a list from a TCL Proc?

Tags: tcl

I have the following code -

```
#Create a list, call it 'p'
set p {dut.m0.x,dut.m1.y,dut.m2.z,dut.m3.z,dut.a0.vout}

#Here is a procedure to return this list 
proc get_ie_conn_ports {ie} {
        global p
        set my_list {}
        foreach n [split $p ","] {
        lappend my_list $n
    }
    return [list $my_list]
}

#This procedure call the previous procedure to retrieve the list
#It then prints it
proc print_ports_and_direction {ie} {

    set ie_ports [get_ie_conn_ports ie]
    puts $ie_ports
    foreach n [split $ie_ports (|\{|\})] {
        puts [string trim $n]
    }


}

#I call the procedure, dont worry about the argument (place holder for now)
print_ports_and_direction "dut.net00.RL_Bidir_ddiscrete_1.8"
```

When this list prints, I get this -

```
dut.m0.x dut.m1.y dut.m2.z dut.m3.z dut.a0.vout
```

The white space is not being accounted for. Please advise as to how I can print each member on a new line. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `ie_ports` is `dut.m0.x dut.m1.y dut.m2.z dut.m3.z dut.a0.vout` and you are trying to split on any one of the characters `( | { } )`, which are not present in `ie_ports`, so you will be left with the whole list.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but you can iterate on the list itself:

```
foreach n $ie_ports {
    puts [string trim $n]
}
```

Another issue is that your procedure `get_ie_conn_ports` is wrapping the list `$my_list` in another list, which is not needed. You should return the list itself:

```
proc get_ie_conn_ports {ie} {
    global p
    set my_list {}
    foreach n [split $p ","] {
        lappend my_list $n
    }
    return $my_list
}
```

---

You might also want to change the following line:

```
set ie_ports [get_ie_conn_ports ie]
```

to

```
set ie_ports [get_ie_conn_ports $ie]
```

---

Running the modifications to your code in [codepad](http://codepad.org/PPxDvEzq) gives the following results where each member are on a line:

```
dut.m0.x
dut.m1.y
dut.m2.z
dut.m3.z
dut.a0.vout
```

Comment: Many thanks Jerry! That absolutely worked! I realized the return from proc get_ie_conn_ports() was a list of a list which causes all the problems... my bad!

Comment: The command `split $p ","` produces a list. There is no need to iterate over that list to effectively produce an exact copy. The proc body could be reduced to `return [split $::p ","]`